# Error:(63, 9) error: cannot find symbol class AppSettingsDetails

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Good evening, I made the import of the last version of the Android module in Android Studio and I have a problem with the regeneration of the APK.

The error that prevents the compilation is located at the `LocaleHelper.java` file. The error returned is:

> Can not resolve symbol ‘AppSettingDetails’” at line 66.
>
> AppSettingsDetails appSettingsDetails = ((App) context.getApplicationContext ()). GetAppSettingsDetails ();

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to import `AppSettingsDetails` class into `LocaleHelper`. Make sure you are importing the right package.

Comment: Thanks sir for your replay .. but how can i set it. How can i kno its right class

Comment: First make sure you have the `AppSettingsDetails ` class in your package.
e.g if it is in `com.vectorcoder.androidecommerce.settings` package then, you have to add  `import com.vectorcoder.androidecommerce.settings.AppSettingsDetails;`